# R difference between class and DMwR package knn functions?

Tags: r

So I was working on a project in R and I ran into a issue with fitting a KNN model to some data. I was getting different results when I ran the knn from class and kNN from DMwR libraries. I tied using the Weekly data from the psych package but I got similar results. Confusion matrices for the fits give significantly different results as does the strait up comparison between between the predictions.

I am not sure why these two functions are returning different results. Maybe someone can review my sample code and let me know what is going on.

```
library(ISLR)
WTrain <- subset(Weekly, Year <= 2008)
WTest <- subset(Weekly, Year >= 2009)

library(caret)
library(class)
fitClass <- knn(train = data.matrix(WTrain$Lag2), test = data.matrix(WTest$Lag2), cl=WTrain$Direction, k=5)
confusionMatrix(data = fitClass, reference = WTest$Direction)

library(DMwR)
fitDMwR <- kNN(Direction~Lag2,train = WTrain, test = WTest, norm=FALSE, k=5)
confusionMatrix(table(fitDMwR == 'Down', WTest$Direction =='Down'))

results <- cbind(fitClass,fitDMwR)
head(results)
```

Comment: I would have provided the the results of the confusion matrix but I am not overly familiar with posting on this site.

Comment: The psych package does not appear to have a dataset called Weekly. Also no package that you loaded above contains a function called confusionMatrix

Comment: If you are not familiar with this site then you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Oh, you are right. It is the ISLR library for Weekly and library(caret) for confusionMatrix. Sorry I should have double checked my code.